# Cucumber class can not resolved

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Whenever I type `@RunWith(Cuccumber.class)`, I am getting the below error:

> Class cannot be resolved to a type

Please let me know what are dependencies I have to change if required.

Comment: In order to know what to change, you need to know what actually is present. Post minimal example.

Comment: You have made an error in typing the Cucumber.class statement, there is an extra c in the fourth location.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fix the typo in `Cuccumber.class`; it should be `Cucumber.class`.
2. If that doesn't work, make sure to import required dependencies for cucumber-jvm